# Can't use findElement in Selenium (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
Then("a Cucumber sentence", async function () {

  await driver.findElements(By.xpath('/html/body'))

});
```

I try to use findElements from Selenium but keep getting

```
ReferenceError: By is not defined
```

anything I can do for this?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen it imported like this (looks weird to me):

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
  By = webdriver.By,
  until = webdriver.until;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import `By` along with other things from Selenium Webdriver as such:

```
const { Builder, By, until } = require('selenium-webdriver');
```